# testdriven.io Getting Error SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

Tags: python, docker

I am working on a tutorial (Test-Driven Development with Python, Flask and Docker) from testdriven.io and in running the command:

```
docker-compose exec api python manage.py recreate_db
```

I am getting the following error:
qlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

From the research I have done this is due to libpq not being the correct version for psycopg2-binary.  I have tired quite a few of the suggestions like having the following in my docker file prior to the requirements:

```
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install curl libpq-dev gcc 1> /dev/null
```

I have also tried using psycopg2 instead of psycopg2-binary.

I tried various docker images, but still cannot proceed past this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My system:
Macbook Pro
Monterey Version 12.1
Apple M1 Pro chip

Requirements.txt file:

```
flask==2.1.1
flask-restx==0.5.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pytest==7.1.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.10.3-slim-buster

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 .
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

#RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install curl libpq-dev gcc 1> /dev/null

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
    && apt-get clean

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -U --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . .

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the help of @Michael Herman.  I used downgraded the postgres image version to 11 from 14 and this resolved the issue.